# Why can i read lines from file only one time?

Tags: python

I have a file containing python's object as string, then i open it and doing things like i showing:

```
>>> file = open('gods.txt')
>>> file.readlines()
["{'brahman': 'impersonal', 'wishnu': 'personal, immortal', 'brahma': 'personal, mortal'}\n"]
```

But then i have problem because there is no longer any lines:

```
>>> f.readlines()
[]
>>> f.readline(0)
''
```

Why it is heppening and how can i stay with access to file's lines?

Comment: `file.readlines()` gives you a list of the lines in the file, but it will read through the entire file. Save it to a variable? `contents = file.readlines()`?

Comment: you can reset to beginning of file with `seek(0)`

Comment: Why file.readlines() could be naturaly be used only one time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your position in the file has moved

```
f = open("/home/usr/stuff", "r")
f.tell()
# shows you're at the start of the file
l = f.readlines()
f.tell()
# now shows your file position is at the end of the file
```

readlines() gives you a list of contents of the file, and you can read that list over and over. It's good practice to close the file after reading it, and then use the contents you've got from the file.  Don't keep trying to read the file contents over and over, you've already got it.

Comment: That is exacly what i need to know. Thank You.

Answer (score 11):

There's only one line in that file, and you just read it. readlines returns a list of all the lines. If you want to re-read the file, you have to do file.seek(0)

Comment: Thank You for this practical knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

save the result to a variable or reopen the file?

```
lines = file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the lines list in a variable and then access it
whenever you want:

```
file = open('gods.txt')
# store the lines list in a variable
lines = file.readlines()
# then you can iterate the list whenever you want
for line in lines:
  print line
```