# Python why is only the first for loop working and the second one not when I try to read this excel file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to have Python read through an excel file and find the maximum and minimum temperature for a set of days. The issue I'm having is that the first for loop functions correctly and all the ones after do not.

```
`weather_data = open("WeatherDataWindows.csv", 'r')
max_temp = 41
for next_line in weather_data:
    next_line = next_line.split(',')
    if next_line[1].isdigit():
        if int(next_line[1]) > max_temp:
            max_temp = int(next_line[1])
print("The max temperature is", max_temp, "degrees")
min_temp = 100
for find_min_temp in weather_data:
    find_min_temp = find_min_temp.split(',')
    if find_min_temp[3].isdigit():
        if int(find_min_temp[3]) < min_temp:
            min_temp = int(find_min_temp[3])
print("The min temperature is", min_temp, "degrees")`
```

When I run this code, the maximum temperature is displayed correctly, however, the minimum temperature simply displays '100'. If I delete the max_temp code from the program, the minimum temperature will display correctly. Why is this happening and what can do to fix it?

Comment: are you sure that `find_min_temp[3]` is the right index? print that value to your console to make sure that you are looking at right values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can i read lines from file only one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522769/why-can-i-read-lines-from-file-only-one-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the position of the read/write pointer within the file points to the end of the file after first for loop.

You can simply write

```
weather_data.seek(0)
```

Before second loop