# iterating through two files in Python 3

Tags: python

I have two text files, I am trying to loop through those two files line by line from the shortest file to the longest file, below are examples of my files:

1- input_file.txt:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

2- Myfile.txt

```
Word1
Word2
Word3
Word4
Word5
Word6
```

I used the below script:

```py
fhand = open('myfile.txt','r')
my_uers = open('input_file.txt','r')

    for n in my_uers:
        n = n.rstrip()
        for lire in fhand:
            lire = lire.rstrip()
            print(n,"-----",lire)
```

The result which I am getting is:

```
Line1 ----- Word1
Line1 ----- Word2
Line1 ----- Word3
Line1 ----- Word4
Line1 ----- Word5
Line1 ----- Word6
```

But the result which I want to get is:

```
Line1 ----- Word1
Line1 ----- Word2
Line1 ----- Word3
Line1 ----- Word4
Line1 ----- Word5
Line1 ----- Word6 
Line2 ----- Word1
Line2 ----- Word2
Line2 ----- Word3
Line2 ----- Word4
Line2 ----- Word5
Line2 ----- Word6 
Line3 ----- Word1
Line3 ----- Word2
Line3 ----- Word3
Line3 ----- Word4
Line3 ----- Word5
Line3 ----- Word6
```

Please can someone help me to find what is wrong in my loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can i read lines from file only one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522769/why-can-i-read-lines-from-file-only-one-time)

Comment: No, it is not answering my question. My issthe loop is stopping in the first line of "input_file.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have read a file, the read pointer is positioned at the end of that file. If you try to read it again, it will start from there, not find any more data, and finish immediately. That's why you only see on iteration. To reset the read position, you can use the `seek()` method, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

```py
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as fhand, \
     open('input_file.txt', 'r') as my_uers:

    for n in my_uers:
        n = n.rstrip()
        fhand.seek(0)
        for lire in fhand:
            lire = lire.rstrip()
            print(n, "-----", lire)
```

You should also get used to using the `with` statement when opening files so that their handles are cleaned up automatically.